# About twitter APIs

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am doing twitter kind of app, when i get all timelines (ie twits) which will have URL or Data or both as a part of feed. How do i know that url from twit has image or video uploaded file link. Is there is any way to know that twit contains media link URL??

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter API does not contain these details yet. I know that they are planning to do so in the future.

In the mean time you have to parse the text yourself and support predefined types of urls in your code

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_entities